# Highlighting the text from the text file by adding span tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to `angular js`and `javascript`. Here, I have document or text file which is lets say like ->

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged
```

Now, In this file I want to highlight the part

```
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
```

So, For highlighting this text from back end I get the offsets which I mean is the startoffset and endoffset of that string.

So, Then I use the following method to highlight the text .

```
$scope.highlightHTML(responseData, startOffset, endOffset);
$scope.highlightHTML = function(content, startoffset, endoffset) {
  var className = 'mark';
  console.log(content.substring(startoffset, endoffset));
  return content.replace(content.substring(startoffset, endoffset), '<span class="' + className + '">$&</span>');
}
```

So, It replaces this text with span tag. Now, Because of this In my array where I have more than 1 elements which I need to highlight in this text.
Because of this the offsets which I get from back end will get changed .So for this I used the following logic ->

```
var length = '<span class="mark"></span>'.length:
jsonDataArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
    responseData = $scope.highlightHTML(responseData, item.startOffset + (index * length), item.endOffset + (index * length));
});
```

But Here is the main problem .

Now lets say Now I want to highlight the text `1500s` , Now here When it comes to find the offset of this string then It will not match with the new multiply logic . Because this `1500's` part is present previously highlighted string.

Previous string will be

```
<span class="mark">Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and</span>
```

Now I want to highlight the `1500s`. Then if I multiply then it will not take the perfect offsets , so will not get the string to highlight.

So, How can I resolve this issue ? Can any one help me with this ?

Comment: Do you think https://plnkr.co/edit/h2mh1MuJGzxOaYFLU7Up?p=preview might be helpful ? If yes, i can provide suggestions over that. U can add color or highlight using same feature

Comment: Yes , you can any Idea will save my day

Answer (score 0):

So, as asked in above comments, you can create a component to apply different styling to the text. [Take a look at this plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/gHNYjJvmt44sxFif7qLC?p=preview), you can also refer [execCommand link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) to find out about more features that you can add.

Eg:

```
 $window.document.execCommand('foreColor', false,'red');
```

will add the color `red` to your text.

And the best part is that you dont have to worry about `styling` and `tags` closing, they all are taken care of automatically.

You can star & watch [this git repo](https://github.com/shashankvivek/RichTextEditor) to be aware of new features that I'll keep adding very soon. I have shown here on how to bind `ng-model` with external component so that you can extract the data out of it as well.

Make sure, you are restricting what things can be done when you apply this feature as you'll be allowed to literally do several things (which might not be an expected behavior in your case). So implement accordingly.

#### Update

[Check this file](https://github.com/shashankvivek/RichTextEditor/blob/master/index.html). You can pull/download the code from Git

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. Actually, I am using TextAngular already .

Comment: Could you please give some idea about the highlighting thing ?

Comment: @ganeshkaspate : Check updated plunkr in the question. All commands are there in links provided. Please go through them

Comment: @ganeshkaspate : I think you should understand business requirement before implementing `textAngular1`, reason being , you wont be able to extend and customize it as per your requirement for everything. For eg: In my editor **you can `add` image from `local machine`**. something that you'll have to explore in textAngular. So consider all aspects and then so for its implementation. Same about adding a table

Comment: Could you please add How to use your editor ? That will help

Comment: @ganeshkaspate: Please check the updated ans and mark it as an answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Why are you going with offset and not the length of the string?
The best option is using jquery which reads the length of the specific text that you want to highlight (as the string text can be dynamic).
1. reach to the first character, then adds the length to the string.
2. highlights the text using the above.

jquery -  $('#... span'), ....focus on your element...
range.setStart(focused element from previous focused element, " + str(
                    result) + ");range.setEnd(end of the focused element," + str(result + len(enter code here
                    name)) + ");sel = window.getSelection();`enter code here`sel.removeAllRanges();sel.addRange(range);"

you can select from any tag and their is no need to add span tags or replace the text.